# How to get a reference to a part of a list without creating a copy in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a collection class derived from `List<T>` and need to perform a packaged `action` on an instance of that collection (i.e. the collection is too large, so I want to split the collection into parts and execute the `action` on the parts). Please note that action has a typed signature, it is some predefined method which expects a collection of the same type.

I do know

```
target.addRange(source.getRange(start, packageSize);
```

but that's not what i want since for this I need a new collection instance and will create copies of the list entries. Since I do know that the action will not manipulate the list in any way I'd preferr to do something like

```
action(source.Reference(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

with the intention to not create copies of the list entries (I know these are 'only' references, but still there is a copy. Is there any way to do that in C#?

Of course I could pass a method to `action` which knows how to retrieve the range, but action should not need to know about my intention to subdivide the execution into parts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If you would explain the downvote I could take your criticism into accout the next time I write a question.

Comment: _I know these are 'only' references_ is exactly why you shouldn't worry about this. You will be making copies of those references constantly, don't solve problems you don't have.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for the input. I will check whether this makes a difference, using the suggestions from the answers I got. The program will ulitmately have to run on a device with limited resource (cpu frequency and memory), not on a common PC, so I developed a habit of being greedy with any kind of resource.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making a copy of the references into a new list, you can use LINQ, or just plain C# to get a part from the list.

Using `Skip` and `Take`:

```
var iterator = source.Skip(start).Take(end - start);
```

Since it is an `IEnumerable`, you can `foreach` over that from within the method called (so you might need to change your method signature):

```
foreach (var x in iterator)
{
    ...
}
```

Or create your own state machine. The resulting enumerable can be passed along to the method too:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(List<T> source, int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        yield return source[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm under the impression that the Linq statement results in a different type. `action` expects the given type as argument.

Comment: So what does your `Action` expect? I told that using `IEnumerable<T>` might need a signature change.

Comment: the collection class derived from `List<T>` I mentioned in the beginning

Comment: Okay, but why does your `Action` need that?

Comment: As mentioned in the (edited) question, it is a given method (which is taken from a library). If I'd written it myself then the Linq approach would work because I could change it.

Comment: Well, than the answer is: you can't. Half an object isn't an object, so you have to create a new instance for just the part you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Linq:

```
var notAList = source.Skip(fromIndex).Take(toIndex-fromIndex);
action(notAList);
```

This way you create enumerator which will enumerate your numbers without instantiating space for all of them.

Comment: Would it not be easier to do `source.Take(toIndex).Skip(fromIndex)`?

Comment: @overactor To me, your example seems to be invalid.

Comment: @overactor that would work, too. But the `Skip` would now be a little bit slower as it cannot take advantage of the source being a `List<T>` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [`Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) for that:

```
public void MyAction<T>(IEnumerable<T> range)
{
    // ...
}
```

and call

```
MyAction(list.Skip(fromIndex).Take(toIndex-fromIndex));
```

Note that this operators (`Skip` and `Take`) use *deferred* execution and evaluated lazy. So you indeed can think of this as a kind of *reference* to the range in the source list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create own iterator:

```
public class MyPartListIterator: IEnumerator
{
    private readonly IList list;
    private readonly int _startIdx;
    private readonly int _endIdx;
    private int _current;

    public MyIterator(IList list, int start, int end)
    {
        //do some validations before etc
        this._startIdx = this._current =  start;
        this._endIdx = end;
        this._list=  list;

    }

    public bool MoveNext() 
    {
       //do some checks against list was changed

       if (this._current >= this._endIdx) return false;
       this._current += 1;
    }

    public object Current => this._list[this._current];

    public void Reset() => this._current = this._startidx;
}
```

Then you can pass instance of iterator to your `action`.

Why it is better than `Skip` and `Take`? It doesn't enumerate elements before starting index.

You can also prepare generic version of course.

Wrtten from memory, not tested. Used C# 6.0 syntax sugars.

**EDIT:**

It is not possible to pass the same reference of `IList<T>` as your big `ILIst<T>` and that contains only part data of source list.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can use Extensions to get the functionality you're looking for.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void PerformActionOnSubset<T>(this IList<T> collection, int fromIndex,
        int toIndex, Action<IList<T>> action)
    {
        action(collection.Skip(fromIndex).Take(toIndex - fromIndex).ToList());
    }
}

myCollectionOfSomethings.PerformActionOnSubset(10, 30, myAction);
```